# How to set proxy with environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` in a raw terminal environment?

Tags: terminal, proxy, environment-variables, http-proxy

I am using clash for proxy. But when installing Linux from raw terminal, there is no clash nor anything installed. Also, due to net work issue (that's why I need proxy), I can't download anything. The only thing I have is a subscription URL and many proxy services info fetched from the URL.
Then, how to use these to make a proxy so that I can get internet access through proxy in the raw terminal?

I know the common answer is setting http_proxy or https_proxy in such format: `http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>` or `http://<name>:<password>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>`.

The question is, with a certain selected proxy server, if using `"http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"`, then the response is `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` from `curl google.com`. If taking the latter format, I wonder what the `name` and `password` should be?